# NSCache UIImage data passing from oneViewController to anotherViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimage, nscache

Let me explain the scenario first. I have an `UIScrollView` and in it, add some `UIButton` as `subView`. In those buttons I'm loading some images (from remote server). I load all the images with `NSMutableURLRequest` and save in `NSCache`. As it takes long time to load, that's why I wanted to use this `NSCache`, so that in other `ViewController`, I don't have to load them again from remote server. So, I pass the `NSCache` to another `ViewController` by `Segue`. Still, I'm not sure is it possible with `NSCache` or not? Please let me know about that. And I'm giving you my code below so that you can take have a look on it.

Thanks a lot in advance. Have a nice day.

**`MainViewController.h`:**

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSTimer *timer;
    int counter;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *adButtonOutLet;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AdInfo *currentAd;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
@property (nonatomic, retain) AdParser *adParser;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *adsListArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *displayArray;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSCache *imageCache;
```

**`MainViewController.m`:**

```
-(void)startAnimation:(id)data
{
    activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(140.0, 525.0, 40.0, 40.0);
    [self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];

    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped=YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self startAnimation:nil];
    self.imageCache = [[NSCache alloc] init];

    [self performSelector:@selector(loadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
    counter = 0;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target: self selector: @selector(handleTimer:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
}

- (void)handleTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    //NSLog(@"counter %i", counter);
    if (counter == [displayArray count])
    {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320, 0) animated:YES];
        counter = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(counter*320, 0) animated:YES];
    }
    counter++;
}

-(void) loadData
{
    adParser = [[AdParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:getXMLURL];
    adsListArray = [adParser ads];
    displayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (AdInfo *adInfo1 in adsListArray)
    {
        AdInfo *adInfo2 = [[AdInfo alloc] init];
        [adInfo2 setBannerIconURL:adInfo1.bannerIconURL];
        [adInfo2 setBannerIconLink:adInfo1.bannerIconLink];
        [displayArray addObject:adInfo2];
    }
    [self loadScrollView];
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}

-(void) loadScrollView
{
    [self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake([displayArray count] * ScrollerWidth, ScrollerHight)];

    for (int i = 0; i < [displayArray count]; i++)
    {
        adButtonOutLet = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*320, 0, ButtonWidth, ButtonHight)];

        currentAd = [displayArray objectAtIndex:i];

        NSString *path = currentAd.bannerIconURL;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
        NSMutableURLRequest *requestWithBodyParams = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        NSData *imageData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestWithBodyParams returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        UIImage *cachedImage =   [self.imageCache objectForKey:currentAd.bannerIconURL];
        if (cachedImage)
        {
            [adButtonOutLet setImage:cachedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.imageCache setObject:originalImage forKey:currentAd.bannerIconURL];
            NSLog(@"tulon %@", self.imageCache);
            [adButtonOutLet setImage:originalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }

        adButtonOutLet.userInteractionEnabled= YES;
        [adButtonOutLet setTag:i];
        [adButtonOutLet addTarget:self action:@selector(goToURL:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self.scrollView addSubview:adButtonOutLet];
    }
}

-(IBAction)goToURL:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSInteger indexValue = sender.tag;
    for (int i = 0; i < [displayArray count]; i++)
    {
        if (indexValue == i)
        {
            currentAd = [displayArray objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *url = currentAd.bannerIconLink;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication]  openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        }
    }
}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"goToSecondViewController"])
    {
        SecondViewController *secondViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        [secondViewController setImageCache:imageCache];
        [secondViewController setDisplayArray:displayArray];
    }
}
```

**`SecondViewController.h`:**

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSTimer *timer;
    int counter;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *adButtonOutLet;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AdInfo *currentAd;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSCache *imageCache;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *displayArray;
```

**`SecondViewController.m`:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.imageCache = [[NSCache alloc] init];
    [self performSelector:@selector(loadScrollView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
    counter = 0;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target: self selector: @selector(handleTimer:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
    NSLog(@"tulon %@", self.imageCache);
}

- (void)handleTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    if (counter == [displayArray count])
    {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320, 0) animated:YES];
        counter = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(counter*320, 0) animated:YES];
    }
    counter++;
}


-(void) loadScrollView
{
    [self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake([displayArray count] * ScrollerWidth, ScrollerHight)];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [displayArray count]; i++)
    {
        adButtonOutLet = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*320, 0, ButtonWidth, ButtonHight)];

        currentAd = [displayArray objectAtIndex:i];
        UIImage *cachedImage =   [self.imageCache objectForKey:currentAd.bannerIconURL];
        [adButtonOutLet setImage:cachedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];


        adButtonOutLet.userInteractionEnabled= YES;
        [adButtonOutLet setTag:i];
        [adButtonOutLet addTarget:self action:@selector(goToURL:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self.scrollView addSubview:adButtonOutLet];
    }
}

-(IBAction)goToURL:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSInteger indexValue = sender.tag;
    for (int i = 0; i < [displayArray count]; i++)
    {
        if (indexValue == i)
        {
            currentAd = [displayArray objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *url = currentAd.bannerIconLink;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication]  openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        }
    }
}
```

**Addition:**
In `SecondViewController` I create `NSCache *imageCache;` again and when I `NSlog` for it, didn't get any value. I think I am missing here something. Or not following appropriate way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In SecondViewController I create NSCache *imageCache; again

**Not needed**

```
self.imageCache = [[NSCache alloc] init];
```

Remove this line, it should work

Comment: I got it. :D When I `alloc` & `init` in `SecondViewController` it creates `imageCache` as a new. :)
Bohut shukriya.

Comment: exactly. you said it:)